# Gathering loudness data from a sound file

Tags: c++, audio

I'm trying to create a graph in C++ of how loud parts of an audio file are, such as Audacity does:

[image]

I'm not sure where to start however, and what data I'm looking for within the audio file. If it helps any, I'm already using OpenAL to play the sound.

On top of that, what I'm looking to accomplish is have silence within the audio file be represented by 0, and the loudest part of the audio file be represented by 1. Everything in between will be a decimal.

Comment: It depends on the kind of file(s) you want to handle.